# Reload page with encoded parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to redirect after a click to the same page, but with added parameters. I need the redirect to be the current page with `#!/cart` added to the end of the URL (e.g., myurl.com/mypage.html#!/cart).

This is what I'm trying

```
 $('#show_cart_flowers').click(function() {
 window.location.replace("mypage.html#!/cart"); 
 });
```

I've also tried: `window.location.search += '%23!%2Fcart';`

Either way, I end up with a URL like this:`myurl.com/mypage.html?%23!%2Fcart`

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting `window.location.hash`:

```
$('#show_cart_flowers').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.hash = '!/cart';
});
```

Comment: This just added `#` to the url after redirect and didn't include `!/cart`

Comment: Actually...looking at it more closely, it looks like `#!/cart` is added, but the `!/cart` part is almost instantly removed.

Comment: That sounds like an issue somewhere else in your code. Do you have any client routing libraries in use?

Comment: I tried it with no libraries (except jquery) loaded and got the same result.

Comment: Figured it out. Had a stray `href="#"` in my div.

Comment: That'll do it :) You can leave that in to keep the HTML valid and use `event.preventDefault()` in the click handler to stop it affecting the code I posted. I updated the example for you.